# JwtSecurityTokenHandler not registered in IoC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, autofac

I have the following code in asp.net core 2.2:

```
public class JwtTokenManager : IJwtTokenManager
{
    private readonly JwtBearerSettings jwtBearerSettings;
    private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler;

    public JwtTokenManager(IOptions<JwtBearerSettings> options,
                            JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler)
    {
        this.jwtSecurityTokenHandler = jwtSecurityTokenHandler;
        jwtBearerSettings = options.Value;
    }
```

When I try to run the project I get the following error:

```
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'IdentityTemplate.Infrastructure.Security.Jwt.JwtTokenManager' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
Cannot resolve parameter 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler jwtSecurityTokenHandler' of constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[IdentityTemplate.Domain.Users.CustomUser], Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[IdentityTemplate.Infrastructure.Security.Jwt.JwtBearerSettings], System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler)'.
```

Does anyone know how can I register the `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`?

### Update (Added startup.cs)

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("App"));
        services.Configure<JwtBearerSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("JwtBearerSettings"));
        services.Configure<EmailSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings"));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<CustomUser>(config =>
                    {
                        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
                    })
                .AddRoles<RoleExtended>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // ===== Add Jwt Authentication ========
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                    {
                        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

                    })
                .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
                    {
                        cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        cfg.SaveToken = true;
                        cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                        {
                            ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtBearerSettings:Issuer"],
                            ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtBearerSettings:Issuer"],
                            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtBearerSettings:SecurityKey"])),
                            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                        };
                    });


        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);


        services.AddHttpClient();

        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        // Register the Swagger generator, defining 1 or more Swagger documents
        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
        });
    }

    public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        BootstrapConfig.Register(builder);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
        });

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
        // specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
        });


        loggerFactory.AddLog4Net();
    }
```

Comment: Show you startup file

Comment: You are not supposed to inject it. `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` has a parameterless constructor, is not disposable and has the same lifetime as its parent. Just `new` it

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Updated post with Startup.cs

Comment: You can register it with `services.AddScoped<JwtSecurityTokenHandler>();`.

Comment: I know I can do it this way but I was under the impression that I shouldn't ```AddJwtBearer``` should take care of this isn't it?

Comment: No, _AddJwtBearer_ just add an authentication scheme it don't register things like _JwtSecurityTokenHandler_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AddJwtBearer` registers [Authentication Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=aspnetcore2x) for Jwt authorization not more not less. if you want to inject `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` in your class for testing case, just register it in asp.net core built-in container into *ConfigureService* method otherwise you can new it directly.

```cs
services.AddScoped<JwtSecurityTokenHandler>();
```