# Blazor WebAssembly - Suitable constructor for type 'JwtSecurityTokenHandler' could not be located

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, blazor

Edit: 10-27-20 
I am rewriting this post as after more then a week I now both have a better understanding of the issue as well as the solution. 
1st the issue:
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: A suitable constructor for type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.**JwtSecurityTokenHandler' could not be located**. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ResultCache lifetime, System.Type serviceType, System.Type implementationType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain callSiteChain) <0x2f1fb80 + 0x00086> in :0

...
Originally I though this was tied to Azure, but it was not.  It was tied to compiling my project under Release not Debug.

> Old Selection Below - Please Disregard and Jump To Answer =>

When I am testing my Blazor App on my computer I do not get any errors, but as soon as I publish to my Azure App Service I get a very long set of error...

crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
Unhandled exception rendering component: A suitable constructor for type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteFactory.CreateConstructorCallSite (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ResultCache lifetime, System.Type serviceType, System.Type implementationType, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteChain callSiteChain) <0x2f1fb80 + 0x00086> in :0

...

I understand the injection system is looking for JwtSecurityTokenHandler, but is unable to find it.  I use this same configuration for a older MVC API without web UI and it works great, and like I stated it woks on my local system, but on Azure I get an error.  I know I am missing something simple, but I am unable to find it.

Thank you for checking this one out.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{

     //Other DI Here


     services.AddScoped<JwtSecurityTokenHandler>();


        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                // Identity made Cookie authentication the default.
                // However, we want JWT Bearer Auth to be the default.
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg  =>
            {
                // Configure JWT Bearer Auth to expect our security key
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters =
                    new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        LifetimeValidator = (before, expires, token, param) =>
                        {
                            return expires > DateTime.UtcNow;
                        },
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["JwtIssuer"],
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["JwtAudience"],
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["JwtSecretKey"]))
                    };
            });

                  services.AddScoped<IInventoryAdjustmentRepository, InventoryAdjustmentRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IEmployeeDataRepository, EmployeeDataRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IPartDataRepository, PartDataRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IInventoryScheduleRepository, InventoryScheduleRepository>();

 }
```

EDIT: Client Config

```
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

        builder.Services.AddScoped<JwtSecurityTokenHandler>();

        builder.Services.AddScoped<ApiAuthStateProvider, ApiAuthStateProvider>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(p => p.GetService<ApiAuthStateProvider>());

        builder.Services.AddTransient<IAuthenticationContract, UserServices>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmployeeDataContract, EmployeeService>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IPartRepository, PartRepository>();
        builder.Services.AddTransient<IInventorySchedule, InventorySchedule>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBrowserLocalStorage, BrowserLocalStorage>();
        builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBrowserSessionStorage, BrowserSessionStorage>();

        builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
        
        builder.Services.AddSyncfusionBlazor();
        //Syncfusion.Licensing...

        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

       
        builder.Services.AddApiAuthorization();

    
        await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Comment: You're already doing it the way [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57849520/jwtsecuritytokenhandler-not-registered-in-ioc) suggests... so the only thing I can contribute is to point out a comment from user Tseng on that other question... he said: "You are not supposed to inject it. `JwtSecurityTokenHandler` has a parameterless constructor, is not disposable and has the same lifetime as its parent. Just `new` it"... I can't offer any idea or reason why it works locally but not in Azure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I read that as well and was puzzled by the response. It is true you create a token with a new token, but this issue appears to be in the DI not the creation of a token. That being said I think the issues is on the client app not the server API. I am able to use postman to get a token and access authorized API endpoints on the server.  I am looking into the DI of the client side. This is my first go at Blazor web assembly and I chose the ‘all in one’ template when I started.  I will edit my post with my client configuration soon to see if that is were my issue is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: 10-27-20** 
My project was a default Blazor WebAssembly (PWA) with no authentication and .net core hosted backend. The authentication was created using JwtSecurityTokenHandler as its main authentication
To narrow it down the issue was in the client (UI) code.  Within the client to solve the problem I made the following changes.

**Solution:** 
Within the overloaded AuthenticationStateProvider I created a new Token Handler instead of using DI as I was originally.

```
 public class ApiAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
 {
        //Here was the 1st issue
        private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler _tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        private readonly IBrowserLocalStorage _localStorage;

        private readonly HttpClient client;

        private readonly IBrowserSessionStorage _sessionStorage;

        public ApiAuthStateProvider(IBrowserLocalStorage localStorage, HttpClient _client, IBrowserSessionStorage sessionStorage)
        {
            client = _client;
            _sessionStorage = sessionStorage;
            _localStorage = localStorage;
        } 

       ...
```

Next I found on https://github.com/mono/linker/issues/870 where others were having a similar issue.  
 It instructed that adding the following to the main program would prevent the linker from killing the JwtSecurityTokenHandler:

```
        _ = new JwtHeader();

        _ = new JwtPayload();
```

Finally, in the main code I removed the following line as I was no longer using DI:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<JwtSecurityTokenHandler>();
```

Now it works everywhere Release, Debug, Azure, Local, ...

> Please Disregard Everything Below...It had nothing to do with fixing the issue.

Found my solution...In the end the issue ended up not being code related.

I think the issue was related to the default application setting created when you make a
Azure App Service, but I did several changes at the same time.  I have outlined all my changes below.

Configuration -> General Settings

1. Platform : 32 bit to 64 bit
2. Always on: Off to On

[image: Azure App Service General Config]

Configuration -> Application Settings

1. I removed the default 6 items added during the creation / first publication of the app
2. I went back in after I took this screen shot and added my database and application insights back in though the Azure Portal

[image: Azure App Service Application Settings config]

Extensions: Add ASP.NET Core 3.0 and 3.1 runtimes

- These were already there from something I did a few days ago, but just incase I want to make sure I listed all my customizations

[image: Azure App Service Extension]

After all that I went back to the overview and did a restart on the top bar.  I then went back to my page and no errors!  I also republished several times reverting back all my code changes and it continued working.